# Get Azure AD Connect Sync status trough API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

For some software I'm developing I want to know if the Azure AD Connect sync to Office 365/Azure AD is successful. The software is Cloud based and has no connection to the on-premise. The Office 365 Dashboard uses this url (https://admin.microsoft.com/admin/api/DirSyncManagement/manage) to get this information. I can't find a similar function in the Graph API to retrieve this information. Does anyone know a way to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of this is available in public-facing APIs, but some things are. Using the current labels from the Microsoft 365 Admin portal:

- "Directory sync enabled": `onPremisesSyncEnabled` from Microsoft Graph (v1.0) [organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/organization?view=graph-rest-1.0) entity
- "Last directory sync": `onPremisesLastSyncDateTime` from Microsoft Graph (v1.0) [organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/organization?view=graph-rest-1.0) entity
- "Password sync": `onPremisesLastPasswordSyncDateTime` from Microsoft Graph (beta) [organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/organization?view=graph-rest-beta) entity

All of these plus "Directory sync service account" and "Password sync enabled" are currently available with the older Azure AD PowerShell module ([MSOnline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/?view=azureadps-1.0)). With .NET Framework, you could use C# to run [Get-MsolCompanyInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msolcompanyinformation?view=azureadps-1.0) and get what you need from the results (using the `-AdGraphAccessToken` parameter of `Connect-MsolService` to provide an access token you obtain using [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet), for example), but in my experience, trying to do this with .NET Core is often not worth the effort.)

Comment: Use C# and API Graph (REST) ?