# Password Sync Enabled value MS Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am working with MS Graph to determine the Directory Sync Features values. The other values are available such as **"onPremisesSyncEnabled"** but **"passwordSync"** is not available through **"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/organization"** endpoint.

The **"passwordSync"** could be accessed through **"Get-MsolDirSyncFeatures -Feature PasswordSync"**.

Please let me know how to access the passwordSync enabled value through graph.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could get `onPremisesLastPasswordSyncDateTime` when requesting the endpoint even though it is not included in the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/organization?view=graph-rest-beta#properties). Please try with [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#).

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/organization
```

[image]

For more details, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57186070/13308381).

Comment: This seems correct, but if it is enabled and disabled within a few days , the value is not NULL for onPremisesLastPasswordSyncDateTime, it has value. This gives wrong value for Enable/Disable. So, I think this property is not 100% reliable.  Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, there is no property to show you enable or disable. `onPremisesLastPasswordSyncDateTime` will return the time and date at which the tenant was the last password synced,  looks like "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z". Using PowerShell ([MSOnline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/?view=azureadps-1.0)) is the only way. If you use C#, you could try to run Powershell script in C#, plz refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7.1).